# Danger of using std::sort with vector of shared_ptr in multi-threaded world

Tags: multithreading, sorting, c++11, boost, vector

This is simplified version(C++11) of issue I am facing when I upgraded an app to multithreaded world. Essentially I have vector of shared_ptr and I am doing std::sort on it. When multiple threads try to sort it, I can understand, its dangerous as while sorting, first time, iterators may have to move around. But, here, I already have a sorted vector . Now calling, std::sort on it shouldn't impose any trouble(that's what I thought as nothing needs to move) but it's crashing, randomly.( now why I call std::sort on a sorted container, actually, in original code, data is unsorted, but that doesn't matter for end result it seems). Here is sample code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>  
const int MAX = 4;
#define LOOP_COUNT 200

struct Container {
    int priority;
    Container(int priority_)
        : priority( priority_)
    {} 
};

struct StrategySorter {
    int operator()( const boost::shared_ptr<Container>& v1_,
        const boost::shared_ptr<Container>& v2_ )
    {
      return v1_->priority > v2_->priority;    
    } 
 };

std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Container>> _creators;

void func() {    
    for(int i=0; i < LOOP_COUNT; ++i)    {
      std::sort( _creators.begin(), _creators.end(),  StrategySorter() );
    } 
}
int main()
{

   int priority[] = {100, 245, 312, 423, 597, 656, 732 };
   size_t size = sizeof(priority)/sizeof(int);

   for(int i=0; i < size; ++i)
   {
      _creators.push_back(boost::shared_ptr<Container>(new Container(priority[i])));
   }

   std::thread t[MAX];
   for(int i=0;i < MAX; i++)
   {
      t[i] = std::thread(func);
   }

   for(int i=0;i < MAX; i++)
   {
      t[i].join();
   }
}
```

Error :
../boost_1_56_0/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:648: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access::type boost::shared_ptr::operator->() const [with T = Container; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access::type = Container*]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.

Having raw pointers doesn't crash it, so it's specific to shared_ptr.
Protecting std::sort with mutex is preventing crash. 
I am not able to understand why this scenario should result into inconsistent behavior.

Comment: You have no guarantee whatsoever that sorting a sorted array won't move elements back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that a sort that ends up not moving elements will not write.

It could want to move pivots around, sort some stuff backwards in an intermediate stage, or even call `swap(a,a)` without a self-check optimization (as the check might be more expensive than the swap).

In any case, an operation that if it doesn't do nothing is UB is a horrible operation to invoke.

Here is a sort guaranteed to do nothing if nothing is to be done:

```
template<class C, class Cmp>
void my_sort( C& c, Cmp cmp ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  if (std::is_sorted( begin(c), end(c), cmp ))
    return;
  std::sort( begin(c), end(c), cmp );
}
```

but I wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 2):

When more than one thread accesses the same data without synchronisation and at least one of them is doing a modifying operation, it is a race condition and as such, Undefined Behaviour. Anything can happen.

`std::sort` requires mutable iterators to operate, so it is by definition a modifying operation, therefore applying it concurrently to overlapping ranges withough synchronisation is a race condition (and thus UB).